flutter_launcher_icons package is not changing the launcher icons in android after upgrading to the latest flutter version
its my code in pubspec.yaml file:
    dev_dependencies:
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter
      flutter_lints: ^4.0.0
      bloc_test:
      hive_generator:
      build_runner:
      change_app_package_name: ^1.1.0
      flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.14.1

    flutter_launcher_icons:
      android: "launcher_icon"
      ios: true
      remove_alpha_ios: true
      image_path: "assets/images/logodark.png"
      min_sdk_android: 24 

anfter runningdart run flutter_launcher_icons command it says that the icon changes and no error. but when i run it on a real android device no icon is there.
its happend after the uprade the flutter to the latest version

After lots of researching i found the solution:
Video Solution: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhOJ2FunYg8
I added 2 more parameters to the flutter_launcher_icons Now it look like this:
    flutter_launcher_icons:
      android: "launcher_icon"
      ios: true
      remove_alpha_ios: true
      image_path: "assets/images/logodark.png"
      min_sdk_android: 24 # android min sdk min:16, default 21
      adaptive_icon_background: "#ffffff" # You can use a color or image for the background
      adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/images/logodark.png" # For adaptive icons on Android

and then i run flutter clean and then flutter pub get and then flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
and now its working 100% fine on IOS and android for me.
I hope your problem get fixed as well

Helpful bro, thank you

still not work for me :(, the floating icon still black even though the icons in the menu is changing

Sometimes, cleaning the project and rebuilding it can resolve such issues.
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons
flutter build apk

Make sure that the AndroidManifest.xml file is correctly referencing the new icon. It should look something like this:
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="YourAppName"
    ...>

This may help you to resolve it.

no it doesn’t work in my case

This one helps me with Android icon showing as black background
